# Iterating through JSON array for a List in Dashing

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm trying to create a List in Dashing and I've managed to bring in my external JSON, but I'm having problems iterating through it to create the new JSON array to post it out to my List widget. Here's the current code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

name_list = Hash.new({ value: 0 })


SCHEDULER.every '10s' do
    json = File.read('/Users/research/inoutdash/sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/list.json')
    response = JSON.parse(json)

    name_list[response] = {label: response.keys, value: response.values}
    send_event('whosHere', { items: name_list.values })
    puts response.keys
    puts response.values
end
```

Here's my JSON file it's reading from:

```
{
  "Mike":"Here",
  "Jon": "Out"
}
```

The output to the widget currently looks like this:

1. MikeJon Here,Out

How to I properly iterate through the parsed json `response` and pass it to the `send_event`?

Just in reply to Matt's question:

So what I need is one 'whosHere' event with all the values from the JSON file formatted for the List widget - which needs JSON formatted as label: X, value: Y.

So what I need it to do is format it as a json array with:

```
label: "Mike", value: "Here"
label: "Jon", value: "Out"
```

where now it's storing as:

```
label: Mike,Jon, value:Here,out
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want the output to be? i.e., what do you want send_event to send out? One 'whosHere' event for every user? Or one event for all users who are "Here", and another for all users who are "Out"? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` to accomplish this. It iterates over a collection and returns an `Array` where each element is the result of a block.

```
name_list = response.collect { |(name, status)| { :label => name, :value => status } }

# [{:label=>"Mike", :value=>"Here"}, {:label=>"Jon", :value=>"Out"}]
```